# Can't convert from @stateless to @stateful beans

Tags: dependency-injection, glassfish, ejb, stateless, stateful

I'm having a problem instantiating a stateful session bean on glassfish3.1.

A @ManagedBean (session scoped) of a JSF application used to use a @Local interface of a @Stateless session bean and everything worked fine.

Now I had to convert to a @Stateful bean and I'm getting an exception when I try to inject the stateful bean into the mannaged bean.

The code in question consists of the following 3 layers:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ShopBean { 
    private @EJB ShopAdminInterface sa;
    ...
}

@Local
public interface ShopAdminInterface {
    .... some interfaces
}

@Stateful
public class ShopAdmin implements ShopAdminInterface {
    @EJB CoreClassEAO s;
    ... some implementation
}
```

The CoreClassEAO presents an access layer to the database and looks like this:

```
@Stateful
public class CoreClassEAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
    .... access to my persistence interface
}
```

In the last version, when the ShopAdmin and CoreClassEAO both were @Stateless beans everything worked perfectly. But now, injecting ShopAdminInterface throws an exception at me

Update: I narrowed down the problem: See my other question
[Injecting @Stateful bean into another @Stateful bean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8120326/1032152)