# Injecting @Stateful bean into another @Stateful bean

Tags: dependency-injection, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1, stateful

On a glassfish 3.1 server, I have a `@Stateful` session bean which is injected into another stateful session bean.

The stateful session bean which is injected presents my entity access layer, it itself has it's EntityManager injected with `@PersistenceContext` and it looks like this.

```
@Stateful
MyEAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    MyEAO() {
      // default constructor
    }

    ....
}
```

This access layer is injected into another stateful bean:

```
@Stateful
public class ShopAdmin implements ShopAdminInterface {
    @EJB MyEAO;

    ....
}
```

This worked!  - BUT NOW as soon as I added another constructor to MyEAO, injecting MyEAO into the 2nd bean fails with an exception.

The strange thing is, that both beans used to be `@Stateless` session beans in the past and there were no problems at all.

BTW, I used the second constructor to pass the entity manager for my JUnit tests which run outside of the glassfish container.

Short: In the "stateless era" everything worked as expected!

I'm quite new to EJB - so what am I missing here ?

Here is the stack trace:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Bei der Ressourcen-Einspeisung auf dem verwalteten Bean securityGuardBean ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:211)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:99)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:127)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:217)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2508)
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2129)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2077)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:286)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:244)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:108)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:232)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Local ejb-ref name=de.sdata.service.SecurityGuardBean/sgi,Local 3.x interface =de.sdata.service.SecurityGuardInterface resolved to intra-app EJB SecurityGuard in module sdataEJB.jar,ejb-link=sdataEJB.jar#SecurityGuard,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session into class de.sdata.service.SecurityGuardBean: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/de.sdata.service.SecurityGuardBean/sgi' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:194)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:205)
... 48 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Local ejb-ref name=de.sdata.service.SecurityGuardBean/sgi,Local 3.x interface =de.sdata.service.SecurityGuardInterface resolved to intra-app EJB SecurityGuard in module sdataEJB.jar,ejb-link=sdataEJB.jar#SecurityGuard,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session into class de.sdata.service.SecurityGuardBean: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/de.sdata.service.SecurityGuardBean/sgi' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:703)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:470)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:171)
at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:184)
... 49 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/de.sdata.service.SecurityGuardBean/sgi' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound for java:comp/env/de.sdata.service.SecurityGuardBean/sgi [Root exception is java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException]]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:599)
... 52 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound for java:comp/env/de.sdata.service.SecurityGuardBean/sgi [Root exception is java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:242)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:498)
... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at $Proxy273.create(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.resolveEjbRefObject(EJBUtils.java:366)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:190)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1106)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:776)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:744)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:172)
... 57 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: ERROR creating stateful SessionBean
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer.createEJBLocalBusinessObjectImpl(StatefulSessionContainer.java:551)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEJBLocalBusinessObjectImpl(BaseContainer.java:2486)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalHomeImpl.createEJBLocalBusinessObjectImpl(EJBLocalHomeImpl.java:117)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalHomeInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalHomeInvocationHandler.java:177)
... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: de.sdata.service._SecurityGuard_Serializable
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer._constructEJBInstance(StatefulSessionContainer.java:566)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEjbInstanceAndContext(BaseContainer.java:1643)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer.createBeanInstance(StatefulSessionContainer.java:578)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer.createEJBLocalBusinessObjectImpl(StatefulSessionContainer.java:532)
... 67 more
```

Comment: "fails with an exception." -can you paste the trace ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you don't have an explicit no-arg constructor in your class.

IMO it is not a good solution to add special constructor to the bean class because you need to
set some field for the tests. There are some nice tools that can do a lot of tricks for you.
Take a look at http://unitils.org/cookbook.html -->Test a JPA DAO which should be what you need.

Best,
A

Comment: Actually there is a explicit default constructor - good guess. The second constructor was used to inject an EntityManager for my junit-out-of-container-testing. I just changed the constructor into a regular function and use a 2-step setup: m = new MyBean(); m->inject(em); and everything is working again; however I still don't understand what is going on here. And yes, injecting via reflection would be an option too.

Comment: I know this doesn't solve your original problem, but your EntityManager is package-private. By default, test classes are in the same package as the tested class. You could then just use the field access to set your EntityManager: `new MyBean().em = yourEm`